# new keyword in Railo vs ACF

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I am currently checking compatibility between Railo and Adobe ColdFusion.

```
 <cfscript>
 param request.objCycle             = new model.cycle();
 ...
```

Just dies on Railo.

```
 Message string Invalid Identifier.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the `new` operator, it's to do with `param`. There's a bug in Railo in that it won't allow for scoped variables in that context. [Details here](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/way-to-make-me-feel-thick-sean-by.html).

You will have to use this syntax:

```
param name="request.objCycle" default="#new model.cycle()#";
```